# Compare two columns (from one row) with two other columns (from all rows)

Tags: shell, csv, awk

Problem 1: For each row of *file.csv* compare columns 1 and 2 with columns 3 and 4. All fields are separated by '`,`'.
Solution:  `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ;{if ($1==$3 && $2==$4) print $1,$2,$3,$4,"MATCH"}; {if ($1!=$3||$2!=$4) print $1,$2,$3,$4,"UNMATCH"}' file.csv > file2.csv`

The above comparison takes place line-by-line.

Problem 2: For each row of *file.csv*, compare columns 1 and 2 with the columns 3 and 4 from *all* the rows.  If it matches, then `print $1,$2,$3,$4,"MATCH"`. If it doesn't then print `$1,$2,$3,$4,"UNMATCH"`.  Here note that `$3,$4` needn't be from the same row as `$1,$2`.
If *file.csv* has *n* lines, the output should be *n^2* lines.

We were able to solve Problem 1.  But can someone advise on Problem 2 ?

Comment: please complement your question with some [mcve].

Comment: I read `$1` and `$2` from the 1st row and I find that `$3 `of , say, row 3 equals `$1` and` $4` of row 7 equals `$2`. Is this a match? or need you that the matching `$3` and `$4` come from the same row?

Comment: You have a worse problem in your `Problem 2`. From what I understand, it's a many-to-many relationship unlike in `Problem 1` where it's one-to-one relationship. Having said this, how do you expect, or what defines a `$1,$2,$3,$4 UNMATCH` when `$1,$2` is not found in any of `$3,$4`? Which `$3,$4` should be printed along with `$1,$2`? All of them? So, if you have a 5 line file, the unmatched will print 25 lines if all of them are unique?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a match ONLY when `$3` and `$4` come from the same row,
you can accumulate couples of vaues for each row and, at the end, perform a double loop on the saved couples to find the matches.

```
$ cat 1234.csv 
1,2,3,4
4,5,6,7
7,7,1,2
$ awk -F, '    {V12[NR]=$1","$2;V34[NR]=$3","$4} # accumulate couples of values
           END{for(i in V12)
                   for(j in V34)
                       if(V12[i]==V34[j]) print i, j, V12[i], V34[j]}' 1234.csv
1 3 1,2 1,2
$
```

Comment: Sorry gboffi if I was unclear. The problem is we have 4 columns separated by comma. The first two columns will be compared last 2 columns for exact match for in the rows. e.g. consider it to be 6X4 matrix ( 6 rows and 4 columns), and in 1st row two columns values needs to be compared with values in the last two columns in all the rows. If there is match, print all four columns with an additional column saying "MATCH". if it doesn't match, then print all four columns (eg.1,1,,,UNMATCH or ,,,2,2, UNMATCH) with an additional column saying "UNMATCH".

Comment: So as you said, "I read $1 and $2 from the 1st row and I find that $3 of , say, row 3 equals $1 and` $4` of row 3 equals $2.". This is what I want.

Comment: If you really want to print all pairs, MATCHing or UNMATCHing, you'll get a lot, or more accurately A LOT of output, as the number of pairs is quadratic with the number of lines in your `.csv`. If you really really need that output, use an `else` clause after the last `if` and modify the `print` arguments.

Comment: @ErAB - If you have A cols of B rows, why not make an A x B matrix? From here, you can use the same method you did with `Problem 1`.

Comment: It looks like the leading `1 3` in the output are the respective rows of the matches.  That's more useful than the OP's spec, though not actually *part* of it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1 Test input:

```
echo "1,2,3,4
2,1,3,4
1,2,1,2" > file.csv
```

Problem #1 Code:

```
while IFS=, read a b c d e ; do \
    x=MATCH ; \
    [ "$a$b" != "$c$d" ] && x=UN$x ; \
    echo "$a,$b,$c,$d: $x" ; \
done < file.csv
```

Problem #1 Output:

```
1,2,3,4: UNMATCH
2,1,3,4: UNMATCH
1,2,1,2: MATCH
```

Problem #2 Code, (note code re-use of Problem #1):

```
cut -d',' -f1,2 file.csv > 12.csv ; \
cut -d',' -f3,4 file.csv > 34.csv ; \
while IFS=, read a ; do \
    while read b ; do \
        echo $a,$b ; \
    done < 34.csv ; \
done < 12.csv | \
while IFS=, read a b c d e ; do \
    x=MATCH ; \
    [ "$a$b" != "$c$d" ] && x=UN$x ; \
    echo "$a,$b,$c,$d: $x" ; \
done ; \
rm 12.csv 34.csv
```

Problem #2 output:

```
1,2,3,4: UNMATCH
1,2,3,4: UNMATCH
1,2,1,2: MATCH
2,1,3,4: UNMATCH
2,1,3,4: UNMATCH
2,1,1,2: UNMATCH
1,2,3,4: UNMATCH
1,2,3,4: UNMATCH
1,2,1,2: MATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

> compare ... column 1 and column 2 to every field in the 3rd and 4th column

That's a cartesian product of the first pair of columns with the second pair.

You know how to use **awk** to print columns 1 and 2.  A separate invocation will print 3 and 4.  You can use **comm**(1) to find the matches and non-matches of those two sets, and awk again to convert that output as desired.

I recommend **comm**(1) over loops and arrays in awk because it should perform better and scale better with large inputs.  With a some cleverness, you can set up the whole shebang as a pipeline, avoiding temporary files and getting parallel execution in the bargain.

Answer (score 0):

with `join/awk` combination, using @agc's input file

```
$ join -j99 -t, -o1.1,1.2,2.3,2.4 file.csv{,} | 
  awk -F, '{print $0, (($1==$3 && $2==$4)?"":"UN") "MATCH"}'

1,2,3,4 UNMATCH
1,2,3,4 UNMATCH
1,2,1,2 MATCH
2,1,3,4 UNMATCH
2,1,3,4 UNMATCH
2,1,1,2 UNMATCH
1,2,3,4 UNMATCH
1,2,3,4 UNMATCH
1,2,1,2 MATCH
```